# My printer is not printing cause of a error message. 16.04 Cannon MX330

Tags: 16.04, printing

I really have had nothing but trouble printing on this setup.  The thing is right now I can print if I start a live version of the OS.  This is the second install I've done on this computer.  The first installation also had printing issues.  The problem is also that I don't really know my way around on Ubuntu.

The printing error message is - `There is a missing print filter for printer 'MX330-series'`.

Comment: AFAIK, Cannon printers require proprietary drivers.

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/